# square roots in multiplicative group of integers modulo n

Tags: finite-groups, residue-calculus, quadratic-residues

How do I exactly determine all solutions for square roots if they exists and what to do if for one square root exist two solutions?

Let's for example take the Group $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})$ with 
        \begin{align*}
   &1\cdot1\equiv1\mod7\\
   &2\cdot2\equiv4\mod7\\
   &3\cdot3\equiv2\mod7\\
   &4\cdot4\equiv2\mod7\\
   &5\cdot5\equiv4\mod7\\
   &6\cdot6\equiv1\mod7
  \end{align*}

The formula used here is for elliptic curve computation in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$:
        \begin{align*}
   y&\equiv\sqrt{0^3+0+1}\equiv1\mod 7\\
   y&\equiv\sqrt{1^3+1+1}\equiv\sqrt{3}\mod7\text{ no solution}\\%\approx\pm1.732\\
   y&\equiv\sqrt{2^3+2+1}\equiv\sqrt{4}\equiv5\mod7\\
   y&\equiv\sqrt{3^3+3+1}\equiv\sqrt{31}\equiv\sqrt{3}\text{ no solution}\\%\approx\pm5.568\\
   y&\equiv\sqrt{4^3+4+1}\equiv\sqrt{69}\equiv\sqrt{6}\text{ no solution}\\%\approx\pm8.306\\
   y&\equiv\sqrt{5^3+5+1}\equiv\sqrt{131}\equiv\sqrt{5}\text{ no solution}\\%\approx\pm11.446\\
   y&\equiv\sqrt{6^3+6+1}\equiv\sqrt{223}\equiv\sqrt{6}\text{ no solution}\\%\approx\pm14.933\\
   y&\equiv\sqrt{2^3+2+1}\equiv\sqrt{11}\equiv\sqrt{4}\equiv5\mod7\\%\approx\pm3.317\\
   y&\equiv\sqrt{3^3+3+1}\equiv\sqrt{31}\equiv\sqrt{3}\text{ no solution}\\%\approx\pm5.568\\
   y&\equiv\sqrt{4^3+4+1}\equiv\sqrt{69}\equiv\sqrt{6}\text{ no solution}\\%\approx\pm8.306\\
   y&\equiv\sqrt{5^3+5+1}\equiv\sqrt{131}\equiv\sqrt{5}\text{ no solution}\\%\approx\pm11.446\\
   y&\equiv\sqrt{6^3+6+1}\equiv\sqrt{223}\equiv\sqrt{6}\text{ no solution}%\approx\pm14.933
  \end{align*}
For every square are two solutions possible. I think one of these has to be something similar like the negative solution (e.g. $-4\equiv3\mod 7$) even if like somebody said negative solutions doesn't exist (what I still think is crap because of $\mathbb{Z}$). How to determine which in every case is the correct one?
Can two solutions for one x exist for for an elliptic curve computation in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$?

Concerning the negative number problem I add a different question:

Why is $3\equiv\sqrt{2}\equiv4\mod7$ when it isn't?

This question probably also explains my confusion.

Comment: The notion of "being negative" makes no sense modulo $n$.

Comment: That was just my explanation for the results, please feel free to answer the question and also explain the correct usage of terms to me in this answer.

Comment: This is not clear.  What are you asking?  You appear to be looking at the polynomial $n^3+n+1$.  Is that correct?

Comment: You seem to be asking about square roots in the multiplication table (not the addition table) of the ring $ \mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z}$. That is a deep question with no straightforward answer: it's the study of _quadratic residues_ in elementary number theory. The first part of your table shows that each of $1$, $2$ and $4$ has two square roots modulo $7$. They are $a$ and $7-a$.

Comment: the formula is from ECC curve calculation in residue groups but for my problem it probably doesn't matter. My problem is that I receive two results and don't know how to evaluate them.

Comment: Two results for what?  Please state the precise problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: my ecc curve would have to points for one x value that shouldn't be I think (not sure)

Comment: No idea what that means, sorry.  Maybe there's a lot of context here that you have omitted.  As it stands, I don't think it's at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: To decide whether or not an element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a square, the standard strategy (that I know) is to use chinese-remainder-theorem and then consider the case of $\mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ is a prime. It has something to do with the Legendre's symbol. If the element is not a square, one cannot find its square-root. I suppose you're asking how to find the square root in case it exist?

Comment: If that's the case I propose that you rewrite your question and omit the unnecessary context :) or you provide specific context and ask a more specific question :)

Comment: Yep, thought it was clear no I idea what I missed, can you make a proposal how to change the question that it displays exactly what you said? (I also give it a try)

Comment: Your question seems to have something to do with the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+x+1$  over the field with $7$ elements.  Are you asking what points are on the curve?

Comment: You can say so, but primarily I am interested in getting a solution for how to evaluate the correct solutions for taking squar roots in groups of integers modulo n. So I don't would like to have a more general answer that doesn't only focusses on elliptic curves.

Comment: “Negative” solutions simply have no meaning modulo $n$.  If $-k$ is a solution, then so is $n-k$ and $2n-k$, etc., and the usual approach is to use the representative from the congruence class that falls in the interval $[0,n-1]$.

Comment: Hmm, so much trouble here at the beginning, now is all quiet and I still have no answer, how to formulate my question correct? Could you correct my question in your answer. The comments felt like you all are experts in the field and know the answer but now it seems like nobody likes to share his knowledge with me.

Comment: There isn't really anything like *the square root function modulo n*. But, you mention elliptic curve crypto. What matters there are the solutions in the field $\Bbb{Z}/7\Bbb{Z}$ to the equation of a curve, here apparently $y^2=x^3+x+1$. For example, with $x=0$ you want solutions of $y^2=1$ which are $y=1$ and $y=-1=6$ (the field is fixed to $\Bbb{Z}/7\Bbb{Z}$ so I prefer not to use the congruence notation as "everything is done modulo seven").

Comment: Anyway, as usual, the two solutions of $y^2=a$ (if any exist) **in a field** are negatives of each other. $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ is a field if and only if $n$ is a prime number. If the modulus is a non-prime, the number of solutions may blow up. For example $\pm1$ and $\pm4$ are the four solutions of the congruence $y^2\equiv1\pmod{15}$.

Comment: How do I know (when there is a solution that is the negative of the other one) which is it else I will receive even with my prime modulus 4 solutions for two square roots